# <select> dropdown not working on chrome mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-chrome

I don't know why but for some reason my select is not working at Chrome mobile view.

I have a simple `select` like this:

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

It works on every other mobile/desktop browser.

I can see the `<select>` but when I tap it, the dropdown it doesn't work, it doesn't open showing the `<option>`.

I have to say that I'm using Angular Material (I won't use md-select for mobile views).

Comment: All the posts I  saw are talking about it's a bug in Chrome. Take a look at this link, the last 2 comments, maybe helps: https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/select-component-is-not-working-in-android-for-ionic-angular-js-app

Comment: thanks @tomyforever I also read this thread and also read this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8181 its useful, but it's still not working.